# Append text in a span to hidden input

Tags: jquery, append, hidden, hidden-field

I have a span (#sum) which changes dynamically, adding up the values of selected options in a form. I want to append the text from this to the value of a hidden input field so I can email the figure.

So my html is

```
<span id="sum">£0.00</span>
```

and my hidden field is

```
<input type="hidden" name="total" value=""  />
```

But using jQuery that needs to read

```
<input type="hidden" name="total" value="[WHATEVER THE NUMBER IN THE SUM SPAN IS]"  />
```

Here is the jQuery I have so far:

```
var total = $('#sum').html();
    $('#total').val(total);
```

Comment: Just add an id = "total" to the hidden field ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input name="total" type="hidden" id="total" value=""  />
```

You are referring to it by id. Add the id

Comment: You also need to keep the name.

Comment: @Barmar why do you say we need the name?

Comment: Because that's what gets sent to the server when the form is submitted.

Comment: @Barmar. It refers to it in JS, so it doesn't do a form submit in the sample, but there is no harm in keeping it if need be

Comment: He's using JS to fill in the form field, he never said he's using AJAX to submit it. And even if he is, if he uses something like `.serialize()` to post it, it needs a name.